# SwipeListView setSwipeMode none is disabling onclick as well as swipe

Tags: android

Hi am using a SwipeListView  that has two buttons on its back view i'm trying to programatically set the SwipeListView so that it doesn't swipe by setting the swipe mode to none. the problem i am having is the front view is now not registering the click. Does any one know why???

Heres what i have tried so far

```
final SwipeListView messagesList = (SwipeListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
if(r_deleteMessages == false || r_markMessages == false) messagesList.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_NONE);

if(messageData != null){
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = messagesList.getLayoutParams();
    int size;
    size = messageData.size();
    params.height = (SM_Global.pxFromDp(context, 80) * size) +3;

    messagesList.setLayoutParams(params);
    messagesList.requestLayout();

    messagesList.setFocusable(false);
    final MessagesAdapter messagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(context, R.layout.layout_message_item, messageData,messagesList,"profile");
    messagesList.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);



        Log.v("Auth","CAN READ MESSAGES | " + r_readMessages);
        messagesList.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
                 super.onClickFrontView(position);
                Log.v("Auth","CLICKED ");


            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: Hey Jigar & iamlukeyb, did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Listener to the list view and override `onChangeSwipeMode`

```
if(r_deleteMessages == false || r_markMessages == false){

    mList.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
        @Override
        public int onChangeSwipeMode(int position) {
            return SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_NONE;
        }
    });
}
```

This way you will still get touch events.

You may also need to do `mList.setSwipeOpenOnLongPress(false);` to disablr the long click

see: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggested ways but didn't work for me. So I made changes in my List Adapter & handled the click event there. Now it is working fine.